# Visual studio 2012 пишет Symbols loaded

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, отладка

Когда запускаю любой проект она мне пишет

```
ConsoleApplication3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Лабы\Laba1\Debug\ConsoleApplication3.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\syswow64\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication3.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll'
'ConsoleApplication3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\syswow64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcp110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'ConsoleApplication3.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\syswow64\msvcr110d.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x1650 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1c64 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x1850 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[5872] ConsoleApplication3.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Началось, когда переустановила вижлу. Что делать?

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, перейти из Debug в Release?..

Comment: @Harry все равно, то же самое пишет

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? Все в порядке.

Comment: @arrowd раньше оно компилило без system("pause")  и не выводилось то, что я написала выше. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы компилятор этого не писал?

Comment: Это пишет не компилятор, а отладчик, скорее. Можно переключить окошко из "Debug" в "Output", если вам это так надо. А насчет `system("pause")` вообще не понял.

Comment: @arrowd я не нашла, где перейти из Debug в Output, только в Release, можете поподробнее объяснить, если вам не трудно

Comment: Это переключается в том же окне, где выводятся сообщения из вашего поста.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53027/discussion-between---and-arrowd).

Comment: Подобная ошибка может возникать, если у вас есть несколько проектов с одинаковым именем. Тем более вы переустанавливали студию. Например у вас уже был ConsoleApplication1-->Вы переустановили студию--> Создали еще один проект с именем ConsoleApplication1-->Возникла ошибка. Возможно, причина в этом